# Firefox webExtension - re-write "redirectURL" in HTTP POST response

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm writing my first webExtension for Firefox. It targets a particular feature on one website, and essentially needs to rewrite the "redirectURL" value in the server response to a HTTP POST (I want it to stop refreshing the page after certain buttons are clicked).

I'm having trouble with this. So far, I've tried webRequest.onHeadersReceived, but the "redirectURL" value isn't in the headers. I've also tried a filterResponseData, but "redirectURL" value isn't in the content of the response either. I captured the full transaction using browser dev tools, and here is the relevant part:

```
"response": {
          "status": 302,
          "statusText": "Found",
          "httpVersion": "HTTP/2.0",
          "headers": [
            {
              "name": "date",
              "value": "Fri, 05 Jul 2019 13:06:18 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-type",
              "value": "text/html; charset=utf-8"
            },
            {
              "name": "location",
              "value": "https://www.strava.com/clubs/2140/members"
            },
            {
              "name": "cache-control",
              "value": "no-cache, no-store"
            },
            {
              "name": "via",
              "value": "1.1 linkerd"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-download-options",
              "value": "noopen"
            },
            {
              "name": "pragma",
              "value": "no-cache"
            },
            {
              "name": "status",
              "value": "302 Found"
            },
            {
              "name": "expires",
              "value": "Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:00:00 GMT"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-request-id",
              "value": "5ff9a2b9-e9b4-453e-9e4e-d42e1ffdd09c"
            },
            {
              "name": "referrer-policy",
              "value": "strict-origin-when-cross-origin"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-frame-options",
              "value": "SAMEORIGIN,DENY"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-content-type-options",
              "value": "nosniff"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-permitted-cross-domain-policies",
              "value": "none"
            },
            {
              "name": "x-xss-protection",
              "value": "1; mode=block"
            },
            {
              "name": "content-encoding",
              "value": "gzip"
            },
            {
              "name": "X-Firefox-Spdy",
              "value": "h2"
            }
          ],
          "cookies": [],
          "content": {
            "mimeType": "text/html; charset=utf-8",
            "size": 119109,
            "comment": "Response bodies are not included."
          },
          "redirectURL": "https://www.strava.com/clubs/1234/members", <-- I want to re-write this
          "headersSize": 597,
          "bodySize": 29832
        },
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

The redirect URL is in the [`location` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Location). The line you marked in the HAR is merely an indication of the action the browser took.

So you can intercept the response and change said header:

```
function modifyRedir(details)
{
  for (let header of details.responseHeaders) {
    if (header.name.toLowerCase() == "location")
    {
      header.value = "<some URL>";
    }
  }
  return {responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders};
}

browser.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(
  modifyRedir,
  {
    urls: ["<URL this should be applied to>"]
  },
  ["blocking", "responseHeaders"]
);
```

Alternatively, you could also just overwrite the redirect

```
function modifyRedir(details)
{
  return {redirectUrl: "<some URL>"};
}
```